# "Load more" content from the server and add it to the page

Tags: ember.js, pagination, ember-cli

I've waded through a lot of pages/questions regarding pagination/infinite scrolling/load more content.

Either the content is pre-loaded completely in the store or the examples requesting new data simply don't work.

I've got a blog displaying 5 posts then a 'load more' button.
Upon hitting this button I'd like to request 5 more posts from the server and add them live to the page.

`this.store.find('post', {limit: 5, offset: 5, sort:'createdAt desc'});`

Please can you provide a working example or instructions to make it work?

*EDIT:* the following seems to be a good option but I don't know how to make it work

> Make the model a standard array and use the route hooks and "load more" actions to fill it with records from ED query results

*EDIT2* this is how I set the model for the route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
      return this.store.find('post', { isPublished: true,
                                       limit: 5,
                                       sort:'createdAt desc'});
   }
});
```

Comment: This should work.  Where is this code and if it gets hit are you seeing a request to your api for data or no?

Comment: The data is requested and retrieved from the server successfully but it won't be added to my template.

Comment: The find command just loads the models and then push them into the store. You probably need to push those records into the controller(its model property) that's driving the page.

Comment: Can you post your code for how you're setting the model for the route?

Comment: Yes it helped me resolve my trouble. Thanks a lot :) I ditched the query params though.

Comment: alright :) I hope that you killed two birds with one stone - solved the problem and learnt how the query params work + know how to use them if you go for pagination / whatever in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created a simple app for you on GitHub:

https://github.com/andrusieczko/ember-loadMore-example

Just fetch it, install dependencies and you're ready to go:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/andrusieczko/ember-loadMore-example.git
$ cd ember-loadMore-example
$ npm install
$ bower install # possibly you don't have to do that
$ npm start
```

and go to `http://localhost:4200` where you have a link to `#/post` route.

I've presented how you can do `loadMore` button but I set up the `offset` variable as well, so you can easily transform this code to the pagination.

So, in my `routes/post.js` file I've got two query params defined (though in this example I'm actually using only `limit`):

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    limit: {
      refreshModel: true
    },
    offset: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },

  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('post', {
      limit: params.limit,
      offset: params.offset
    });
  }
});
```

That sets up both of the query params. `refreshModel: true` causes fetching new data from server (`model` hook is called) whenever a query param is changed.

To have it working, you have to also define your query params in the controller (`controllers/post.js`):

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['limit', 'offset'],
  limit: 20,
  offset: 0,

  pageSize: 20,

  actions: {
    loadMore: function() {
      this.set('limit', this.get('limit') + this.get('pageSize'));
    }
  }
});
```

And the `loadMore` action is just adding the `pageSize` to existing `limit`.

The template (`templates/post.hbs`) look like that:

```
<h1>Posts</h1>

<ul>
  {{#each post in model}}
    <li>{{post.id}}. {{post.name}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

<button {{action 'loadMore'}}>Load more</button>
```

To have the fully working example, I've created a simple server side that can understand `limit` and `offset`:

```
app.get('/api/posts', function(req, res) {
  var limit = parseInt(req.query.limit);
  var offset = parseInt(req.query.offset) || 0;

  var filteredItems = items;
  if (limit) {
    filteredItems = items.slice(offset, (offset+limit));
  } else {
    filteredItems = items.slice(offset);
  }
  res.send({
    post: filteredItems
  });
});
```

where `items` is an 100-elements array of `[{id: 0, name: 'post0'},{id: 1, name: 'post1'},...`.

Hence the `model` structure (`models/post.js`):

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I hope that it will help you to understand how to implement the solution in your project.

Enjoy!

Comment: Does Ember re-render the entire list of posts again? Or does it simply add the newest posts to the DOM? For example if you've clicked "Load More" for the 20th time, does it render all 100 posts, or just posts 96-100?

Comment: hey, sorry for late answer... ember does not re-render the entire list, it checks which nodes have changed / been added and renders only them.

Comment: But in this approach your backend needs to send all the previous data next to the new one. Isn't there a way to do this with requests like:
1 request: limit: 20 offset: 0,
2 request: limit: 20 offset: 20,
3 request: limit: 20 offset: 40

Not like this:
1 request: limit: 20 offset: 0,
2 request: limit: 40 offset: 0,
3 request: limit: 60 offset: 0
?